# WCF File-less Activation Metadata

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service I'm writing, trying out the file-less activation introduced in .NET 4.0. I'm trying to get the service to return the WSDL, and while I have the web.config configured in a pretty basic manner, I cannot get the service to emit a WSDL. ?wsdl and ?singlewsdl return just the normal service page rather than the WSDL.

I'm using .NET 4.5 for this

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ods">
        <endpoint address="localhost" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="co.ods" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"><!--aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"--> 
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="ods.svc" service="co.ods" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I assume there is an issue with the configuration, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: We add <WebMethod()>  to each method in the svc.vb file and add an .asmx file in the service root. That produces a classic wsdl by doing .asmx?wsdl

Comment: I have a few questions. Is your service activation successful? A few things that I see on looking at your config (just guesses). (1) service name="ods" (try giving co.ods) (2) contract="co.ods". Is it co.ods again. Have you written the type name instead of contract name? (3) Are you browsing to http://localhost:port/ods.svc?

Comment: @lcryder WebMethod is used with older ASMX services, not WCF, plus the point of file-less activation is to not have a .SVC file.

Comment: @Praburaj (1) Tried this, but with no success. I'm pretty sure that the name="ods" is just a name for reference and does not have a tie back to code for. The only tie is back to the Route. (2) I have written the type rather than the contract name, "co.ods" is just an obfuscation for the sake of SO. (3) I am browser to the proper URL, and I do get the "You have created a service" page (so service activation seems successful), but the WSDL operations simply refresh the page without providing the WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue - I didn't have `ServiceContract` on my interface and I didn't define the methods as `OperationContract` items. Simple mistake. I didn't want to delete the post to help people that make the same mistake.